# Is there a non-trivial cyclic quotient group of a non-cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a non-cyclic group and H be a non-trivial normal subgroup. Can we state that G/H is non-cyclic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $G$ be a direct product of two cyclic groups that is not cyclic, and $H$ the inclusion of one of those groups. For example, $G = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \{e\}$.

Comment: And even more generally, to give a sense for how epically false the statement would be, note that every finitely generated abelian group $G$ is a finite direct product of cyclic groups. Each factor group in this product can be realized as a quotient of $G$ in an analogous way as in this example.

Comment: very nice, thanks!